# How to set Images from URL in Galleryview

Tags: android, image, galleryview

Here is the **CODE** pls guide me to make the changes.

```
package org.androidpeople.gallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GalleryExample extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;

private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4, R.drawable.a_5, R.drawable.a_6, R.drawable.a_7
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(500, 500));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code which is working for you...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Gallery gallery;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final String url="http://www.hugosys.in/www.nett-torg.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Lighthouse3-300x225.jpg";
        String [] strings={"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
            "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
            "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-UBmLbPELvoQ/URqucCdv0kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/IdNhr2VQoQs/s1024/Apre%2525CC%252580s%252520la%252520Pluie.jpg",
            "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-s-AFpvgSeew/URquc6dF-JI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Mt3xNGRUd68/s1024/Backlit%252520Cloud.jpg",
            "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bvmif9a9YOQ/URquea3heHI/AAAAAAAAAbs/rcr6wyeQtAo/s1024/Bee%252520and%252520Flower.jpg"};
         imageLoader=new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
         gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
         gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this,strings));
    }
    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;
        String [] strings;
        public AddImgAdp(Context c,String [] strings) {
            cont = c;
            this.strings=strings;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return strings.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(500, 500));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(strings[position], imgView);
            return imgView;
        }
    }
 }
```

Here the image loader and file cache handler classes..

[FileCache.java](http://pastebin.com/4xhsY9US)

[ImageLoader.java](http://pastebin.com/taLm5ec0)

[Memorycache.java](http://pastebin.com/iBFyTMTr)

[Utils.java](http://pastebin.com/CVK8EUxb)

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this tutorial using `universalImageLoader`  http://regupathybalan.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-universal-image-loader.html

Edit Answer-

Please try this code-

```
package org.androidpeople.gallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GalleryExample extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;

private Integer[] Imgid = {
        R.drawable.a_1, R.drawable.a_2, R.drawable.a_3, R.drawable.a_4, R.drawable.a_5, R.drawable.a_6, R.drawable.a_7
};


protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault("Your activity context"));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

     gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(500, 500));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageLoader.displayImage(
                            "Your Image URL",
                            imgView, options);

        return imgView;
    }
}

}
```

Hope this code helps you!!!
If it is not working please let me know i will try to help you more.

Comment: you can use this code for just set image url in imageview. and for gallery view you have to use base adapter.

Comment: in your getview() Method you can set image in imageview using this universal image loader

Comment: Sorry i don't have complete code. i have only suggesion  for now.

Comment: FYI, It's link only answer, must include essential parts from the original source here because link may no longer exists in future.